# Delete with join in not working-Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a query in codeigniter like,

```
$this->db->join('mail_groups','subscriber.mail_group_id=mail_groups.mail_group_id');
$this->db->where('mail_groups.user_id',$this->user_id);
$this->db->where('subscriber.email_address',$email);
$this->db->delete('subscriber');
```

I am getting this error

[image]

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

Subscriber

[image]

Mail groups

[image]

It is possible to delete with join in Codeigniter?

Comment: Try changing the order, place the join after the where clauses.

Comment: If the mail group id is connecting the two tables why not just delete subscribers? Instead of joining? Also the Join should be last like John mentioned

Comment: @JohnV.,I was tried,But not working

Comment: can you give table structure of subscriber?

Comment: @kumar_v I updated my question,Could you please check it

Comment: Delete with join doesn't work. I've tried it many times. Rather I've used a select and then I've deleted the row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$this->db->where(array("mail_groups.user_id"=>$this->user_id,"subscriber.email_address"=>$email))
           ->join("mail_groups", 'subscriber.mail_group_id=mail_groups.mail_group_id')
           ->delete("subscriber");
```

Comment: Thanks,But it also getting the same error "Unknown column 'mail_groups.user_id' in 'where clause'" :)

Comment: Better you pass it as query instead of using CI join Functions.

Comment: I have done with where_in and inner query without using join,Now my problem solved,But...How to do in codeigniter